# Is angular module dependency list ordered or not?

Tags: angularjs, dependencies

I tend to put the dependencies in the rough order of their usage in my apps, but is there a good practice for this ?
Does the order have any kind of effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic scenario the modules can be loaded in any order and can be sorted for readability purposes - they will be resolved anyway. However, it isn't the case when module services are overriden or mocked:

```
angular.module('originalModule', [])
  .value('service', 'original');

angular.module('mockedModule', [])
  .value('service', 'mocked');
```

In this case

```
angular.module('app', ['mockedModule', 'originalModule']);
```

or

```
angular.module('app', ['originalModule', 'mockedModule']);
```

will result in `service` having 'original' or 'mocked' values, respectively.

This can be used in production, e.g. when some `constant` is supposed to be overriden this way (not a recommended practice if the same purpose can be approached in more meaningful way).

In Angular testing the described behaviour is constantly used to mock services,

```
  beforeEach(module(
    'app',
    { service: 'mocked value' }
  ));
```

Notice that the code above won't work as expected if the modules are listed in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

The modules can be loaded in any order (or even in parallel) because modules delay execution. (Literally from [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)) The "best practice" i use is first the external modules, like ngRoute, ngMessages, ui.bootstrap etc, and then my personal modules like controllers, services, filters, ...